# Rewriting initialization list for each class of complex inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wanted to build complex hierarchy of classes (in this case) for a game.

The problem is - for 3-4 levels of hierarchy it's not a problem, but when I have 10-20 levels of it, then it becomes a real pain. With all these constructor arguments, and base-class constructor calls in initialization list (mostly with the same arguments for each class + current class members), it simply discourages to code.

```
class gameObject
{
public:
    gameObject(const std::string& _name, const size_t& _id)
        : name(_name), id(_id) {/* nothing here */}
    virtual ~gameObject() = 0;
private:
    const std::string name;
    const size_t id;
    //...
};

class item : public gameObject
{
public:
    item(const std::string& _name, const size_t& _id, const unsigned short& _item_lvl, 
         const unsigned short& _required_lvl, const float& _weight, const unsigned& _base_value)
        : gameObject(_name, _id), item_lvl(_item_lvl), required_lvl(_required_lvl), 
          weight(_weight), base_value(_base_value) {/* nothing here */}
private:
    const unsigned short item_lvl;
    const unsigned short required_lvl;
    const float weight;
    const unsigned base_value;
    //...
};

class equipment : public item
{
public:
    equipment(const std::string& _name, const size_t& _id, const unsigned short& _item_lvl, 
              const unsigned short& _required_lvl, const float& _weight, const unsigned& _base_value,
              const std::vector<char>& _allowed_prof, const std::vector<int>& _required_perks, 
              const std::vector<int>& _item_stats,  const short& _item_position, 
              const unsigned short& _efficiency_lvl,
              const std::string& _upgrade_name)
        : item(_name, _id, _item_lvl, _required_lvl, _weight, _base_value), allowed_prof(_allowed_prof), 
          required_perks(_required_perks), item_stats(_item_stats), item_position(_item_position),
          efficiency_lvl(_efficiency_lvl), upgrade_name(_upgrade_name) {/* nothing here */}
private:
    const std::vector<char> allowed_prof;
    const std::vector<int> required_perks;
    const std::vector<int> item_stats;
    const short item_position;
    unsigned short efficiency_lvl;
    std::string upgrade_name;
    //...

    /* tons of other members */
};

class weapon : public equipment
{
public:
    weapon(const std::string& _name, const size_t& _id, const unsigned short& _item_lvl, 
           const unsigned short& _required_lvl, const float& _weight, const unsigned& _base_value,
           const std::vector<char>& _allowed_prof, const std::vector<int>& _required_perks, 
           const std::vector<int>& _item_stats,  const short& _item_position,
           const unsigned short& _efficiency_lvl, const std::string& _upgrade_name)
        : equipment(_name, _id, _item_lvl, _required_lvl, _weight, _base_value, _allowed_prof, 
                    _required_perks, _item_stats, _item_position, _efficiency_lvl, _upgrade_name) 
                    /* TONS OTHER */ { /* nothing here */ }
private:
    // TONS...
};

class melee_weapon : public weapon
{
    // TONS MORE...
};

class one_handed_weapon : public melee_weapon
{
    // MORE MORE TONS...
};

class one_handed_sword : public one_handed_weapon
{
    // MORE MORE MORE MORE MORE MORE MORE MORE MORE MORE...
};
```

Is there a better method of building such hierarchy? Not to rewrite the same things in all constructors over and over?

Comment: Try a Gang of Four Builder pattern.  Your real problem is that this complexity won't go away.  If you have all those attributes, they won't initialize themselves.  Sure you need them all?

Comment: I agree a builder or factory pattern will help. Another possibility is to use generic key-attribute pairs, though then you lose static typing, so it's easier to make errors. After that, when you still have problems that the language you're using won't help you solve, it's time to think about defining your own "little language" and processing that to generate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is a neat tool, but sometimes it is not the best solution to your problems. In your case, it would seem that is it overused.

I would encourage you to familiarize yourself with [design patterns](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/gofpatterns.aspx). They offer great solutions for recuring programming dilemmas and problems.

In your case, something like the [composite pattern](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Composite.aspx) could be practical.

Also, maybe some classes don't need to be directly GameObjects? Maybe you could separate your logic in different modules?

Hope this helps!